# Closed contour in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a set of points (`std::pair` of `double`) on a 2D plan and I want to apply a mask (wich is a closed contour : square, circle, polygon...) to it. **If a point is contained by the mask (or under the mask), it does not appear, otherwise it appears.**

For example, if the mask is a rectangle with `(m_x,m_y)` the coordinates of its top-left corner and `m_width` and `m_height` its width and height, a point would be contained in the mask (and should not appear) if :

```
if (x >= m_x && x <= m_x + m_width && y >= m_y && y <= m_y + m_height) 
        return true;
```

For simple shapes (rectangle, circle) it is not that difficult, **but how would you do it/what would you use to consider more difficult shapes like polygons ?** Is Qt (5.6) doing that ? Or should I use something like OpenCv ?

**EDIT 1**

Qt can do it with the QPolygonF class (thanks Aurélien) but do you know if the std is doing that ? We implemented our data libraries without any other library than the std, if we can continue it would be great, if not it's not a problem.

Comment: No, the C++ standard library does not contain any geometry primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the QPolygonF class.

There is a QPolygonF::containsPoint method.

## Edit

I don't know any std way to do that, but it's simple to implement :

[Point in Polygon Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716268/point-in-polygon-algorithm)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84226/Is-a-Point-inside-a-Polygon

Comment: There is also `QPainterPath` that can combine multiple shapes (including ellipses) and also has `contains` method.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119627/how-to-test-if-a-point-is-inside-of-a-convex-polygon-in-2d-integer-coordinates You can implement it yourself. Be careful of that special cases